`--single-transaction` equivalent for mysqlsh util.dumpSchema
My database is using InnoDB, and when using mysqldump I have the option to set --single-transaction to avoid locking the tables while still having a consistent view of them.
I'm trying to switch over to the recommended MySQL Shell util.dumpSchema, and I only see two options: consistent: true and consistent: false. The documentation for consistent: true specifies that the tables will be locked for backup.
Is it possible to use util.dumpSchema to dump in a single transaction via InnoDB in the same way? Or is this done automatically if the tables use InnoDB?

DumpSchema utility uses multiple threads to dump tables in parallel (read the about section on the page you linked in the question). Each thread runs in its own transaction, so it is impossible to dump the whole database in a single transaction.
This is why the utility applies global or table level read locks if the consistent mode is enabled. It has the same effect as the single transaction option in mysqldump: the backup will be consistent.
